# When will copyright on Rick Riordan's Percy Jackson book series expire?

Tags: percy-jackson, copyright, rick-riordan

When, in the future will copyright on Rick Riordan's [*Percy Jackson*](https://rickriordan.com/series/percy-jackson-and-the-olympians/) book series expire?

Note: Rick Riordan is a US-based writer, so US copyright law applies here.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_law_of_the_United_States (In short, 70 years after the date when — or if — he dies, subject to any future changes in the law).

Comment: Probably a better fit for Law Stack Exchange; I'd imagine the answer will vary based on country too (in the UK, copyright on books expires 70 years after the author's death).

Comment: Riordan is 59 years old and seems in good health. There is a good chance he will reach average life expectancy in the US, which is 77 years, and live until 2041. The copyright for his works will expire 70 years later, in 2111. I know from your questions on Writing.SE that you wish to use Riordan's worldbuilding in your own writing. But in 88 years you will likely be dead. And if not, waiting that long just to steal someone's ideas doesn't promise to lead to a good life in my eyes. Why not simply come up with your own ideas and write something else?

Comment: Note that U.S. copyright law only applies to publications in the U.S.  That's the whole point of the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention), to create reciprocal recognition of other countries' copyrights.  That said, the rules are not exactly the same; for example, Australia only recently (2019) changed from life+50 to life+70.  (Boo!)  Fair use/fair dealing exemptions also vary widely as do numerous other details.  It would be more useful to say if _you_ live in the U.S.

Comment: @Ben Or obtain the author's permission. It can't hurt to write to him and ask.

Comment: @Showsni +1, but if you go this route, it may depend on the local laws and on who holds the copyright. You may have to ask this kind of thing to the publisher and not the author. But anyway, in the case of popular authors, for any practical purposes you'd certainly have to go through the publisher first, no matter who holds the copyright.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Some number of years years after he dies

In the USA, that number is 70. However, [copyright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries%27_copyright_lengths#:%7E:text=Under%20the%20Convention%2C%20the%20duration,years%20after%20the%20author%27s%20death.) will last in other parts of the world for different times.

Some countries subscribe to the [*rule of the shorter term*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_the_shorter_term) (which means their term if shorter than the USA's, or the USA's if not), and some don't. Some continue copyright to the end of the year, and some don't.

As of this moment, he is not dead.